# Why are all symmetry groups of regular polytopes are finite Coxeter groups.

Tags: symmetry, polytopes, coxeter-groups

Why are all symmetry groups of regular polytopes are finite Coxeter groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are [reflection groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group), and Coxeter proved in

> H.S.M. Coxeter, "Discrete groups generated by reflections" Ann. of Math. , 35 (1934) pp. 588–621

and in [this paper in the following year](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/root.systems/references/Coxeter.1935.pdf) that symmetries of polytopes are among the finite reflection groups:

> Coxeter, Harold SM. "The Complete Enumeration of Finite Groups of the Form $R_i^2=(R_i R_j) ^{k_{ij}}= 1$." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 1.1 (1935): 21-25.

Check out either of those two articles: Coxeter is generally easy to read.