# Do isometries of regular convex polytopes generate everything?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polyhedra, polytopes, linear-groups

Let $D$ be a regular convex $d$-dimensional polytope that is symmetric $(D=-D$) in $\mathbb R^d$ centred at the origin. Let $G$ be the group of all isometries of $D$, that is, linear maps/matrices $T\in M_d$ such that $T[D]=D$. Does the linear span of $G$ in $M_d$ generate everything, that is, ${\rm span}\, G = M_d$, the space of all $d\times d$-matrices?

It is the case for $d$-dimensional cubes and octahedrons but is it true in general?

Comment: TY; it's probably for the better to mention it.

Comment: You could do it by a case study. If you already know it for the $d$-cube and even-sided regular polygons (the latter case is probably easy too), there are only three cases left:  dodecahedron, 24-cell and 600-cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this indeed the case. The proof has several ingredients.

1. Burnside's theorem: Suppose that $G< GL(n, {\mathbb C})$ is an **irreducible** subgroup, i.e. a subgroup which does not preserve any proper linear subspace in ${\mathbb C}^n$. Then the linear span of $G$ is the entire group $M_n({\mathbb C})$ of complex $n\times n$ matrices. (Take a look for instance [here](http://www.joelshapiro.org/Pubvit/Downloads/BurnsideThm/burnside.pdf) for a simple proof.)

A consequence of this is that if $G< GL(n, {\mathbb R})$ is **absolutely irreducible**, i.e. it is irreducible as a subgroup of $GL(n, {\mathbb C})$, then the linear span of $G$ is the entire group $M_n({\mathbb R})$ of real $n\times n$ matrices.

2. Suppose that $G< GL(n, {\mathbb R})$ is an irreducible finite reflection group. Then $G$ is absolutely irreducible. See for instance Lemma 2.10 in

W. G. Dwyer , C. W. Wilkerson, [Centers and Coxeter elements](https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/Coxeter.And.Center.pdf).

3. The symmetry group $G$ of any regular convex polytope is a finite reflection group, see [references given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653478/why-are-all-symmetry-groups-of-regular-polytopes-are-finite-coxeter-groups). 
   One can further show that $G$ is irreducible. (I will chase a reference when I have more time.)

When you put all this together, you obtain the proof that the symmetry group of every complex polytope in ${\mathbb R}^n$ spans $M_n({\mathbb R})$.

Comment: Many thanks, Moishe. I was suspecting that this is elementary but having failed to prove it... was still hoping that. I require this fact to justify a certain corollary in a note I am writing. Would you mind if I use this and credit you directly?

Comment: @Jan_Ch. Sure and you are welcome.